# Existe Algum Problema Na Existência de CSS Duplicado, Mas 100% Igual?

Tags: html, css, desempenho

Possuo uma aplicação, onde tenho um arquivo chamado *"layout"* que é responsável por exibir todo `HTML`(head, footer, body apenas para chamar o menu lateral que é um outro arquivo), `CSS` e `Javascript` comuns para todas as páginas dessa minha aplicação.

Todas as páginas da minha aplicação, crio apenas o body delas, pois chamo o layout para exibir o resto. Tudo funciona corretamente até ai.

Houve um momento onde precisei criar um `CSS` personalizado para uma página específica, então no body dessa página inclui esse `CSS` com a tag `<style>`. Porém este momento, teve que ocorrer outras vezes com este mesmo CSS, deixando ele de ser raro na aplicação.

Então coloquei esse `CSS` no arquivo de `CSS` padrão da aplicação, porém como possuo centenas de páginas, esse `CSS` também existe no body dessa página, fazendo com que ele exista em duplicidade quando estas página são acessadas.

Aos poucos estou removendo esse `CSS` dessas páginas e deixando apenas no arquivo de `CSS` padrão.

Esse `CSS` duplicado pode resultar em algum problema de desempenho ou outro problema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problemas no layout da página só se existirem regras diferentes, e nesse caso, se algum elemento for atingido pelas duas regras e tiverem a mesma força, a que for declarada por último é a que valerá.

Quando uma pessoa entra no site pela primeira vez, os primeiros segundos são críticos para captar a atenção e convencê-la a ficar mais um pouco ou a voltar no futuro. Se o seu site demora muito tempo a carregar, a maioria das pessoas desiste e abandona-o, mesmo antes de ter tido oportunidade de lhes mostrar o valor do seu serviço. “Um atraso de um segundo pode resultar em 7% menos conversões, 11% menos visualizações de páginas, ou mesmo uma diminuição de 16 por cento na satisfação do cliente" [BRYAN EISENBERG](http://www.bryaneisenberg.com/how-your-website-loses-7-of-potential-conversions/).

**Código limpo significa carregamento mais rápido e visitantes contentes.**

É importante manter o tempo de carregamento baixo escrevendo código semanticamente adequado, usando as melhores práticas de otimização de performance e, rotineiramente, a limpeza de CSS, HTML e imagens.

Geralmente, o tempo de carregamento do site irá aumentar com sua evolução e isso, de certo modo, é algo já esperado. Por isso é importante fazer essa rotina de limpeza de HTML, CSS e imagens uma parte natural do fluxo de trabalho para garantir uma experiência positiva ao usuário.

Você pode testar a performance do seu site em [Webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/)